# How to save an interface or a lambda type when application process being killed?

Tags: android

I have a fragment that takes a lambda as a constructor parameter. When the app goes into the background, the app process may be killed. And when I navigate back to the app, the data in memory is lost, including the lambda property. I want to save the lambda when the application process is killed in the background.

I tried using onSaveInstanceState, but it can only save primitive data or data that implements Parcelable. How can I achieve the goal of saving a lambda when the app process is killed and restoring it when the fragment is recreated?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to save the lambda when the application process is killed in the background.

That is not an option. Instead, save state data that you can use to rebuild when your application process is restarted (in the saved instance state `Bundle` or some persistent storage).

Comment: Thanks. I will try to save simple data and to restore from it.